# "close" pop-up box bug on mobile site

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web

There's a small bug with the "close" pop-up on the mobile interface; if I've already voted to close, then when I click the "close" link, nothing comes up.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to have been fixed (maybe when we added the "retract vote" feature).

Comment: Wow, kudos to you for keeping even the oldest bugs on your radar. Glad this is fixed.